# How to find categorical data where one category (including NaN) represents at least 80% of all categories of variable in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, categorical-data

I have Pandas DataFrame in Python like below:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 11 | NaN |
| NaN | 10 | NaN |
| ABC | 11 | NaN |
| ABC | 11 | NaN |
| DDD | 12 | NaN |
| ABC | NaN | GAME |

And I need to create list of variables, where one category represents >= 80% of all categories of a given categorical variable. So I need to:

1. Select only categorical variables
2. Make value_counts(dropna=False), because I need to include as categories also missing variables
3. Create list of variables from above DataFrame where one category represents >= 80% of all categories of a given categorical variable

So, as a result I need something like: `my_list = ["COL3"]`, because --> (5xNaN) / 6 rows = 0.83

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: Just for clarification: Are COL1 and COL3 of type 'category' or of type 'object'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use a one-liner, you can apply a lambda function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['ABC', 'NaN', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'DDD', 'ABC'],
               'COL2': [11, 10, 11, 11, 12, 'NaN'],
               'COL3': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'GAME']})

df.apply(lambda x: (100*x.value_counts(dropna=False).iloc[0]/x.shape[0])).to_frame('% One Value')
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Jan answer works, I would like to propose a pandas implementation avoiding using a for loop:

```
#Selects the categories
categories = df.select_dtypes(include='object')
#Fill the nan values with a placeholder 
#(assuming the nans are np.nans and not string representation of nan)
categories = categories.fillna("NO DATA")
#Describe the df to compute the frequencies
description = categories.describe().transpose()
#Select only the ones with highest freq superior to 0.8
my_list = description[description["freq"] > description["count"]*0.8].index.values
```

Output (in my_list):

```
array(['COL3'], dtype=object)
```